# javascript variable DB.transaction

Tags: javascript, variables

```
function initDatabase() {
 try {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Local Databases are not supported by your browser. Please use a Webkit browser for this demo');
    } else {
        var shortName = 'testdb';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'test database';
        var maxSize = 3 * 1024 * 1024; // 3 MB
        DB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
    }
} catch(e) {
    if (e == 2) {
        // Version mismatch.
        console.log("Invalid database version.");
    } else {
        console.log("Unknown error "+ e +".");
    }
    return;
 } 
}

function GetMe() {
 DB.transaction(
    function (transaction) {

    //some other stuffs         
    var ff = 55;


    }
);

 return ff;
}

$(function() { 

    initDatabase();
    alert(GetMe());


});
```

guys help me with this

the GetMe function returns "undefined" and not 55 because the variable "ff" is inside the DB.transaction.

if the variable "ff" was outside the DB.transaction it works perfectly but not if its inside the DB.transaction

can someone tell me how to make it return the "ff" variable inside the DB.transaction

i tried return (DB.transaction.ff); and few other stuff but nothing worked :(

please help me.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question:

> if the variable "ff" was outside the DB.transaction it works perfectly but not if its inside the DB.transaction

The variable `ff` must be outside the function to properly scope it. That is what you want in this case, since you want the parent function to return `ff`:

```
function GetMe() {
   var ff;
   a = function () {
       ff = 55;
   }
   a()
   return ff; // 55
}
```

Comment: `function GetMe() {
 
 var ff;
 
 DB.transaction(
 
  a = function (transaction) {

   transaction.executeSql("SELECT billid FROM bills ORDER BY billid DESC LIMIT 1;", [], b = function (transaction, results) {
    
    if(results.rows.length > 0) {

     var row = results.rows.item(0);
     
     ff = row['billid'];

    } else {
     
     ff = 0;
     
    }
    
   }, errorHandler);
   
   b();
   
  }
 );
 
 a();

 alert(ff);
 return ff;
 
}`